# Matplotlib: change colormap after the fact

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot

I'm charting the progress of a differential equation solver (boundary value problem). Each iteration yields a complete set of function evaluations f(x), which can then be plotted against x. Each graph is (supposedly) closer to the correct solution than the last until convergence is reached. A sequential colormap is used to make earlier graphs faded and later ones saturated.

This works fine when the number of iterations is predetermined:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
cm = plt.get_cmap('OrRd')
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/(iter+1)) for i in range(1,iter+2)]) 

ax.plot(x,y)
for k in range(iter):
    # iterative solve 
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

However, if I use a convergence criterion instead of a predetermined number of iterations, I won't be able to `set_color_cycle` beforehand. And putting that line after the loop doesn't work.

I know that I can store my intermediate results and plot only after convergence is reached, but this strikes me as heavy-handed because I really have no use for all the intermediate results other than to see them on the plot.

So here are my questions:
1. How do I change the colormap of the existing graphs after plotting? (This is easy in MATLAB.)
2. How do I do the same thing with another collection of graphs *on the same plot* (e.g. from a different initial guess, converging to a different solution) without disturbing the first collection, so that two colormaps distinguish the collections from one another. (This should be obvious with the answer to Question 1, but just in case.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `update_colors()` to update the colors of all lines:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
cm = pl.get_cmap('OrRd')

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

def update_colors(ax):
    lines = ax.lines
    colors = cm(np.linspace(0, 1, len(lines)))
    for line, c in zip(lines, colors):
        line.set_color(c)

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
for i in range(10):
    ax.plot(x, x**(1+i*0.1))
    update_colors(ax)
```

Comment: Brilliant. The function can easily be modified to take the number of lines and colormap as options, which takes care of my second question. Just one quick follow-up, are there any practical differences between `import pylab as pl` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`? Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately, if the plot already has an existing legend, this does not change the color of the corresponding entry in the legend as well. Is it possible to extend the approach to change the color of the legend entry as well?

Comment: @bluenote10 call `ax.legend()` after the colors were updated.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `plt.set_cmap`, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap.html) or (more elaborately, scroll down) [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), cmap='magma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.set_cmap('viridis')
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick you could consider is rather than trying to change the colour values after plotting you can use a black overlay with less than 100% transparency to "fade" the past plots, e.g. an alpha of 10% would reduce the brightness of each past plot sequentially.